# Clouser error in go "too many arguments to return"

Tags: go

I am new to go and I am learning go from book "GO_DESIGN_PATTERN" I am new to go but I have decent experience in programming so that book consist of following code (I was on clousers topic)

```
package main
func main(){
 addN := func(m int) {
     return func(n int){
        return m+n
     }
 }
 addFive := addN(5)
 result := addN(6)
 //5 + 6 must print 7
 println(result)
}
```

It is throwing following error

```
./prog.go:4:2: too many arguments to return
    have (func(int))
    want ()
./prog.go:5:2: too many arguments to return
    have (int)
    want ()
./prog.go:8:17: addN(5) used as value
./prog.go:9:16: addN(6) used as value
```

Comment: If your function is supposed to return something you need to specify that in the function's signature, doesn't matter whether it's a closure or not.

Comment: What's this `//5 + 6 must print 7` though? Shouldn't it say `11`?

Comment: aah that make sense got it thanks for your time, just one thing what will be the return type if I am returning a fuction?

Comment: The return type will be the type of the function, i.e. the signature of the function.

Comment: // 5 + 6 must print 7 to understand this part only I want to compile it.

Comment: Also you're calling `addN` twice rather than calling the result of the first `addN` call, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/PLRlrc1kc9C

Comment: yes that is true I will mail it to the publication about this code, but while calling addFive(6) I am getting 11 which is correct

Comment: Since you are starting with Go, I am curious about your dev setup. Am asking about this as your code should not even compile. I will suggest going through a setup like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-go-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-macos#step-5-%E2%80%94-creating-your-go-workspace). Go

Comment: @ParikshitSingh You may want to avoid a book that purports to teach Go while containing such glaring mistakes.

Comment: @poWar note that those errors listed in the question are compiler errors, so the program does *not* compile.

Comment: @poWar That is some good resource, for setup thanks I'll look into it

Comment: @mkopriva I'm thinking the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the type of return value.
`func (a int) int {... return value}` or `func (a int) (b int) {... return}`

Comment: If you add a return type variable name, you must enclose it in parentheses: i.e. `(b int)`

Comment: I apologize, copied it like that